# Как правильно написать for для генератора списка, если на вход поступает разное количество элементов?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Получаю следующую ошибку

```
not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

Моя функция имеет следующий вид

```
    def name_function(self, *expctd):
      expctd = [x for x, y in expctd]
      self._selector_element.should(have.size(len(expctd))) \
        .should(have.exact_texts(*expctd))
```

Сама ошибка и причина понятны. Вопрос в том как правильно переписать for, чтобы учитывать, то что на вход может прийти либо 2, либо 3 элемента в списке expctd?

Comment: Что передаётся в expctd и что должна делать функция name_function?

Comment: Дополнил код, в теле вопроса.
Функция проверяет видимость элемента, проверяет по тексту, который находится в первом элементе получаемого списка. 
Если бы можно было просто оставить в for x, то вопроса бы не было.

Comment: В expctd передается в виде - 'Наименование', 'name' + иногда возможна передача в виде 'Наименование', 'name', 'name_column'

Comment: если в ```expctd``` находятся списки, и вам нужно заполнить массив только первыми элементами этих списков, тогда вам надо написать так: ```expctd = [x[0] for x in expctd]```

Comment: хотя можно использовать просто ```expctd = list(expctd)```

Comment: Да, помогло. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант с

```
expctd = [x[0] for x in expctd]
```

Решил мою проблему на данном этапе.

Comment: Ещё можно было так `[x for x, *_ in expctd]`

Comment: Да, это вариант тоже подходит. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Убрать `, y, z`. Непонятно, для чего они там и что с ними должно происходить.

```
expctd = [x for x in expctd]
```

Comment: Непонятно зачем вообще тогда функция.

Comment: какой-то набор бессмысленных действий. почему не `def name_function(self, *x):`